# Load external html page in a div ( Ionic )

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I am using `[innerHtml]` to load an external HTML page in my ionic app but the URL I am getting is just get printed on the page and not loading the HTML page I want. I don't want to use `iframe` as it reloads my app at some point.

here is my code :

`<div [innerHtml]="myTemplate"></div>`

```
export public class MyComponent {
private webLink: any = "";
constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get("https://www.google.com").map((html:any) => this.webLink= html);
}}
```

someone, please help if I am doing something wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

$('#divWrapper').load('http://localhost:8101/home');

pay attention that if you run on dev mode in ionic things won't work as you expect due to base path